# Save data from RecyclerView in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a list of predefined income categories but the user can also add another categories (by selecting the item New Category). Whenever the user add a new category, I want to save it in the RecyclerView, so that he should not add it everytime.

I understand that I should use SharedPreferences but I don't know in which activity to put it.

This is the Adapter.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private Context context;
private List<Category> lista;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private IncomeCategoryActivity activity;

private static final int CATEGORY_REQUEST=6;

public CategoryAdapter(List<Category> lista, Context context, IncomeCategoryActivity activity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.activity=activity;
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view, activity);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageURI(lista.get(position).getUri());
    holder.textView.setText(lista.get(position).getCategory());
    holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.position = position;
    holder.category=lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageViewCheck;
    public int position;
    public Category category;
    public IncomeCategoryActivity activity;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView, IncomeCategoryActivity activity) {
        super(itemView);
        this.activity=activity;

        imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCategoryImageView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCategoryTextView);
        imageViewCheck=itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCheckImageView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String aux=textView.getText().toString();
        if(aux=="CATEGORIE NOUĂ"){
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, CustomIncomeActivity.class);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CATEGORY_REQUEST);
        }
        else{
            imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, AddIncomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("categorie_venit", aux);
            activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            activity.finish();
        }

    }

}

}
```

This is the activity which contains the RecyclerView.

```
public class IncomeCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView iv_back;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
private ArrayList<Category> lista;

private static final int CATEGORY_REQUEST=6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_income_category);

    iv_back=findViewById(R.id.incomeCatBackImageView);

    loadData();
    saveIncomeCategory();
    lista.add(new Category(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aplicatie_licenta.finalapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.salary),"Salarii"));
    lista.add(new Category(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aplicatie_licenta.finalapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.allowance), "Îndemnizații"));
    lista.add(new Category(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aplicatie_licenta.finalapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.pension), "Pensii"));
    lista.add(new Category(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aplicatie_licenta.finalapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.rent), "Chirii"));
    lista.add(new Category(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aplicatie_licenta.finalapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.scholarship), "Burse"));
    lista.add(new Category(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aplicatie_licenta.finalapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.custom), "CATEGORIE NOUĂ"));

    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.categoryRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    categoryAdapter=new CategoryAdapter(lista, this, this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    iv_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==CATEGORY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            int pozitie=lista.size()-1;
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra("icon");
            String category=data.getStringExtra("category");
            Category c=new Category(uri, category);
            lista.add(pozitie, c);
            categoryAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pozitie);
    }
}

private void saveIncomeCategory(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefIncomeCategoryList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(lista);
    editor.putString("incomeCategoryList", json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefIncomeCategoryList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=sharedPreferences.getString("incomeCategoryList", null);
    Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<Category>>() {}.getType();
    lista=gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if(lista==null){
        lista=new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

}

I watched some tutorials and I built the methods loadData() and saveIncomeCategory() but my app crashes when I start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would want to hook your adapter's on click listener into the parent activity or fragment. In your adapter you would also probably define your own callback.

```
CategoryAdapter ... {
   private OnCategoryClickedListener //Call this callback when it's clicked

   public interface OnCategoryClickedListener{
       public void onCategoryClicked(Category cat...)

}
```

This way you could potentially add the list on another screen but you may want a different interaction when the screen is clicked.

In your activity you would then have the code

```
YourActivity implements CategoryAdapter.OnCategoryClickedListener {

@Override
public void onCategoryClicked(Category c){
    //This is where your shared preferences would go, save the Category or w/e it is you want
}
```

You also just have to set the onCategoryClickedListener from the adapter, probably through the constructor when you create the adapter. Ideally you want to decouple your display logic from your business logic. The adapter would have your display logic but your business logic would be handled elsewhere